# What is the name dialect class for mysql 10.1.21-MariaDB

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

in hibernate.cfg.xml

i am using MariaDBDialect class

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Book</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect</property>

    <mapping class="com.yazeed.brain.dto.User" />
</session-factory>
```

when i run my code i got this errors in console

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling Driver#connect 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'book'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, because MariaDB is 100% compatible with mysql.

Comment: i got exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.yazeed.brain.dto.Humans

Comment: i have class Humans in com.yazeed.brain.dto with @entity annotaion

**@Entity
public class Humans {  }**

Comment: Have you added @Table(name="humans") and also check hibernate configuration should use AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration

Comment: Also check hibernate configuration should use AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration

Comment: `Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
  SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

  Session session = factory.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  session.save(user);
  session.getTransaction().commit();`

Comment: Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure() replace with AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect` instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

probably this is one of the spelling mistake
you can try this instead

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```